# Is it possible to use np.fft.fft to pick out the Fourier coefficients from one timepoint, at a specific frequency?

Tags: fft, phase, eeg, numpy, coherence

I am trying to apply `np.fft.fft` on a 2D array of data of shape (98, 1024), where 98 is the number of trials and 1024 is the sampling rate in Hz. I am trying to find to get the Fourier coefficients at 500 msec (corresponds to the 512th sample) at a frequency of 10Hz. But in my understanding `np.ftt.ftt` returns an array of shape (98, 1024) where 98 is once again the number of trials and 1024 is now the frequencies. So if I'm interested in 10Hz, I can write this code: (correct me if my understanding is wrong)

```py
after_fft = np.fft.fft(timeSeries, axis=1)
frequency_of_interest = after_fft[:, 10]
```

But how can I also keep track of the time information?

I adapted some [code I found online](https://github.com/emma-holmes/Phase-Coherence-for-Python/blob/master/PhaseCoherence.py) to include another parameter for `timePoint`, but I realized there is no where to put the `timePoint` parameter.

I tried reducing the input to just the 512th sample to represent the 500 msec I'm interested in by doing `data = data[:,511, np.newaxis]` and passing that into the function below. However, for a given time, the output for the function (PC) did not vary with frequency, so this approach did not work either.

I looked for functions in python that return a 3D array with dimensions representing (number of trials, timepoints, frequencies). In this case, I could use the `timePoint` to index into `after_fft`, and then index into the specific frequency of interest.

Here is the code below with some print statements I added to understand the data structures better.

```py
def PhaseCoherenceGivenTime(freq, timeSeries, FS, timePoint=None):
    # Get parameters of input data
    nMeasures = np.shape(timeSeries)[0]
    nSamples = np.shape(timeSeries)[1]
    nSecs = nSamples / FS
    print('Number of measurements =', nMeasures)
    print('Number of time samples =', nSamples, '=', nSecs, 'seconds')

    # Calculate FFT for each measurement (spect is freq x measurements)
    spect = np.fft.fft(timeSeries, axis=1)
    print("Spect.shape: ", spect.shape)

    # Normalise by amplitude
    spect = spect / abs(spect)

    # Find spectrum values for frequency bin of interest
    freqRes = 1 / nSecs
    foibin = round(freq / freqRes + 1) - 1
    print('Foibin =', foibin)
    spectFoi = spect[:, foibin]
    print("spectFoi: ", spectFoi)
    print("spectFoi.shape: ", spectFoi.shape)

    # Find individual phase angles per measurement at frequency of interest
    anglesFoi = np.arctan2(spectFoi.imag, spectFoi.real)

    # PC is the root mean square of the sums of the cosines and sines of the angles
    PC = np.sqrt((np.sum(np.cos(anglesFoi)))**2 + (np.sum(np.sin(anglesFoi)))**2) / np.shape(anglesFoi)[0]

    # Print the value
    print('----------------------------------')
    print('Phase coherence value = ' + str("{0:.3f}".format(PC)))

    return anglesFoi, PC
```

Comment: "the Fourier coefficients at 500 msec" -- the Fourier transform has no time information at all. The Short-Time Fourier Transform may be applicable in your case.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! Have a play with [scipy.signal.stft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html) to see if that helps, this is what @MBaz is suggesting. As MBaz says, the Fourier transform by itself has no time information.  The STFT will "window" (localize) the time information and might be what you need.